# Microsoft Graph API - @odata.count value for List messages API is not accurate and consistent

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

I have observed an inconsistent behavior for the @odata.count property returned in response of Microsoft Graph API for Mail. I'm using the API in the following form to get the count of emails in a particular folder of a certain user within a specific time-range:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<UserId>/mailFolders/<folderId>/messages/?$count=true&$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z and receivedDateTime le 2021-02-22T23:59:59Z &$select=body, subject, receivedDateTime, sender, attachments
```

The response of this API is as follows:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('d03264a3-a4c2-4e09-a36b-72769b60c8f3')/mailFolders('AQMkADQwN2JjMTJmLTMyYjEtNDQANjQtYTZjMy1mMzgwZjZkZTc5YWUALgAAAyl9OhZlJyVNuZa50-mFdBYBACL9iHsHcJ1JjFSj-hiqIEkAAAIBEwAAAA%3D%3D')/messages(body,subject,receivedDateTime,sender,attachments)",
"@odata.count": 61,
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAAAi/Yh7B3CdSYxUo/4YqiBJAAAFmeaB\"",
        "id": "AAMkADQwN2JjMTJmLTMyYjEtNDQ2NC1hNmMzLWYzODBmNmRlNzlhZQBGAAAAAAApfToWZSclTbmWudP5hXQWBwAi-Yh7B3CdSYxUo-4YqiBJAAAAAAETAAAi-Yh7B3CdSYxUo-4YqiBJAAACqqzqAAA=",
        "receivedDateTime": "2021-02-10T15:16:04Z",
        "subject": null,
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": ""
        },
        "sender": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Sender"
            }
        }
    },
   .
   .
   .
   {
   }
]
"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userId>/mailFolders('<folderId>')/messages?%24count=true&%24filter=receivedDateTime+ge+2020-01-01T00%3a00%3a00Z+and+receivedDateTime+le+2021-02-22T23%3a59%3a59Z+&%24select=body%2c+subject%2c+receivedDateTime%2c+sender%2c+attachments&%24top=10&%24skip=10"
}
```

Now from my experience, what I've found is that when I move an email in and out of a specific folder, the @odata.count value is not updated right away and takes some variable amount of time to get updated. This might be a expected behavior but I want to be sure about the reason.

But what's strange is that sometimes the @odata.count value is -1. Does this mean anything or there is a bug in the API?

I would like to know the exact reasons of the above two mentioned behaviors as we are using this API in a production integration app and this inconsistency is causing issues. I would be highly thankful if someone officially associated with Microsoft can explain these issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: We never found any solid reason for this behavior and just accepted it as it is. As for -1 value of @odata.count, it happens very rarely in production so we handled this in our application. I assume these are some bugs in MS Graph APIs.

Comment: I am handling in my code too, but trying to get Microsoft to fix this bug because it has two negative side effects; Bad logging of number unread mails, plus need for additional request in a poll.